# If a NSView uses autolayout, do all of its subviews also need to use autolayout for positioning?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have a view in a window, the position and size of the view are calculated with autolayout. The view has a subview, a draggable `NSView` subclass. It is really easy to make a NSView *"draggable"* by overriding `-mouseDown:` and `-mouseDragged:` and changing the frame of the view directly.

The view hierarchy is as follows,
[image: Draggable subview]

What is the best way of making the subview draggable in this case?

For example,

1. Is it possible for the subview to **not** use autolayout, so that it can be positioned by changing the frame directly? i.e. the window positions the main view, but then autolayout does not layout the subview inside the main view. Or do all views in the hierarchy need to use autolayout?
2. When I have used autolayout before, I have used it to make "fixed" layout that respond to resizing. But dragging a view with a mouse does't seems like a natural use-case for autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for the subview to not use autolayout, so that it can be positioned by changing the frame directly?

**Yes.** If you keep `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` turned on, it automatically creates constraints from the values of `frame` and `autoresizingMask`.

In fact, this means it *will* use Auto Layout, but you can work with `frame` just like with manual positioning.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to not avoid auto layout. 
Making a view draggable is pretty easy with auto layout constraint IBOutlets and getting the mouse delta from NSEvent short circuit mouse tracking.